# Stucking on build in Python

Tags: python, android, windows, apk, flet

I installed the `flet` library, and created a project. I wrote my code and tried to build for Android (APK).

I typed this command: `flet build apk`, but at the `Packaging Python App` step the build gets stuck. The result is:

```
Creating Flutter bootstrap project...OK
Customizing app icons and splash images...OK
Generating app icons...OK   
Generating splash screens...OK
Packaging Python app...
```

requirements.txt:

```
flet
```

Minimal reproducible sample:

```
import flet as ft


def main(page: ft.Page):
    page.add(ft.SafeArea(ft.Text("Hello, Flet!")))


ft.app(main)
```

I have tried to build for Windows but it still gets stuck. I installed Git for Windows and added to Path var.

Comment: Use a process viewer that also shows the process child relation in a tree and check what process is the last child that had been executed by the build system (and if has CPU usage and what command-line it was started with). On Windows OU can use Sysinternals Process Explorer from MS.

Answer (score 0):

run the cmd in administrator mode